# Why can't I display this 3D scan correctly?

Tags: texturing, materials, blend-files, packed-data

I downloaded [this model](https://www.turbosquid.com/FullPreview/Index.cfm/ID/1114543) from Turbosquid and I can't seem to get it to display correctly with textures in Blender (am using 2.8). Can anybody suggest a solution?

This is how the model should look in Blender (from the Turbosquid link):
[image]

Here's how it looks in my 2.8. 
[image]
All the textures that should have been packed appear to be missing.

Thanks in advance!
 --Rev

Comment: Apologies, I will fix this. Thanks for feedback.

Comment: The blender version which was used to create the geometry is quite old, probably the developers changed how to pack the images... However, the provided 'obj version' on turbosquid is working for 2.8x.

Comment: That's excellent and frustrating. I tried a couple of formats, but not ye olde .obj. Thanks @brockmann - if you'd like to format your question as an answer I'd be happy to accept it.